# Проблема при добавление папки в репозиторий

Tags: svn

Создал репозиторий

```
igor@igor-desktop:~/test_svn$ svnadmin create /home/igor/svn/repository
```

всё нормально создалось, в папке /home/igor/svn/repository появились файлы: conf, db и т.д.

Хочу добавить в репозиторий папку TreeViewPart1, которая находится в /home/igor/NetBeansProjects/

пишу:

```
igor@igor-desktop:~/test_svn$ svn import FirstPrjoect file:///home/igor/NetBeansProjects/TreeViewPart1 -m "Initial import"
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/igor/NetBeansProjects/TreeViewPart1'
```

прововал и просто:

```
igor@igor-desktop:~/test_svn$ svn import FirstPrjoect /home/igor/NetBeansProjects/TreeViewPart1 -m "Initial import"
svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Invalid URL '/home/igor/NetBeansProjects/TreeViewPart1'
```

что я не так делаю?

Comment: А может внимательнее вику прочитаешь сначала, что бы обвинять людей в низкой квалификации! 
 svn import . svn+ssh://remote.computer/path/to/project -m "First Import" Соответственно сервер, как уже говорилось должен стоять!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да воспользуйтесь [черепахой](http://tortoisesvn.net/) и не парьтесь.

Comment: Я под Linux сижу.

Comment: Ну, тогда [кроликом](http://rabbitvcs.org/). ))

Comment: Есть возможность использования сервиса DropBox. В сети есть статья.

Answer (score 3):

[Создание репозитория проекта](http://rubyclub.com.ua/messages/show/21--%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Subversion)

[SVN_Mini_HowTo](http://astronu.jinr.ru/wiki/index.php/SVN_Mini_HowTo)

Comment: @G71 плюс (это не отмечено в приведенных ссылках) не забудьте, что доступ к репозиторию осуществялется через сервер, в простейшем случае <a href="http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html"/>svnserve</a>.